# PhoneGap Geolocation Not Working in iOS

Tags: javascript, geolocation, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm writing an app that will create a chart based on the user's location. I need to convert the lat lon coordinates from decimal degrees to geographic coordinates. I get to the point where the iPhone asks to share it's location with the app. I'm getting stuck on position.coords.latitude. I'm getting this in the Weinre debugger:

**got here
Error in Success callbackId: Geolocation1810151147 : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.type')**

```
function handleLocationPrompt(results) {  
if (results.buttonIndex === 1) {  

locationStr = results.input1;  

window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gotLocation, onError,{ 
enableHighAccuracy: true});  

function gotLocation(position) {  
console.log("got here");  
var Latitude = position.coords.latitude;  
var Longitude = position.coords.longitude;  

var mp = webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic();  
var latitude = mp.Latitude.toFixed(3);  
var longitude = mp.Longitude.toFixed(3);  

var lat = latitude.toString();  
var lon = longitude.toString();  


var taskParams = {  
 "Latitude": lat,  
  "Longitude": lon,  
"Location": locationStr  

}  


            window.gp_chart.execute(taskParams, gpChartResultAvailable);

            }

            function onError(error) {
        console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

could be a timeout issue. please add timeout to last parameter

{ enableHighAccuracy: true,time}

Comment: added this dict but got the same error  var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
      };

Comment: I think there is a problem with the "position" input to the function. Do I need to declare this variable? I thought position was a built in parameter of the getCurrentPosition function?